# Установка mod_v8 для FreeSwitch в Debian 11

Tags: javascript, debian, модули, node-modules, mod

Всем привет!

ОС Debian 11, хочу включить mod_v8 для работы с JavaScript в FreeSwitch 10.8 (скачиваю отсюда: https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch).

По инструкции:
https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_v8
необходимо сначала "раскомментить"  languages/mod_v8 в файле modules.conf (сделано), а затем выполнить make mod_v8-install

Вопрос: где запускать команду make mod_v8-install?
Потому что где бы я его не запускал в папке freeswitch, получаю сообщение о ошибке "make: *** No rule to make target 'mod_v8-install'.  Stop."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**make mod_v8-install** запускается в папке, из которой собирается FreeSwitch. Эта команда позволяет установить мод отдельно.